# Update looping list in SOQL for loop

Tags: apex

Consider a SOQL for loop

```
for(Account Acc : [Select id,Name FROM Account]){
   Acc.Name = 'Test';
}
```

Now how do I update the list of accounts I queried into? Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you do?

```
Account[] aList = [select id, name from Account];
for (Account a: aList)
   a.name = 'Test';
update aList;
```

or, even better

```
Account[] aList = new List<Account>();
for (Account a : [select id, name from Account])
  aList.add(new Account (id = a.id, name = 'Test'));
update aList;
```

Comment: The first option is my current implementation. I wanted to take a swing a reducing variables - so thought about eliminating the list we query into. The second one is what I was looking for. Thank you.